# Which animals don't have pheromones?

Tags: molecular-biology

Which animals are known to not have pheromones besides humans?

I can't find any research on this. There are examples of every class that uses pheromones. However nobody seems to answer conclusively that any particular species is not likely to have pheromones.

Comment: I'd guess none. If any chemical factor used in an organism's metabolism is volatile, it could be easily released and trigger a response in a nearby organism. And that's essentially a pheromone. Even bacteria do it.

Comment: Ok, does it get more complex if we limit it to sex pheromones?

Comment: Possibly. Approximately half of all animal species (including hammerhead sharks) can reproduce asexually, so it's possible they have less need for sex pheromones. But I'd say it would probably be difficult to show that an animal doesn't use *any* pheromones since there's often thousands of substances released by the animal that could plausibly trigger a response (and how would you test them all?).

Comment: But were there any that were extensively studied and none were found, as in humans?

Comment: I can't say with certainty. Someone else will have to weigh in on that one

Comment: Like for humans, this is not really an answerable question. Even for humans, the absence of pheromones is controversial. Failure to identify a single compound suggests pheromones are not as potent in humans as in certain animals, but cannot rule out their absence entirely.

Comment: Is it likely that all animals besides humans have pheromones? Is there a strong reason that there would be exceptions?